# MS teams 2.0.10 as a channel can't support Multi-turn

Tags: azure-qna-maker

QnAMaker based chat bot can deployed to MS Teams 2.0.8 with multi-turn feature, however the new version 2.0.10 on iPad can't support that. Anyone encountered such issue pls? how to fix? It's frustrated if the higher version is not compatible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Whatever problem you're facing cannot possibly be related to a specific version of Teams not supporting a specific feature of QnA Maker. Channels and channel clients don't know anything about QnA Maker. Only your bot communicates with QnA Maker. It is possible, however, that you've set up your bot to provide QnA Maker follow-up prompts by sending cards to Teams in a way that the iPad client does not support. You will need to provide many details in order for anyone to help solve your problem, such as screenshots and sample code and repro steps. Are you writing a bot using the Bot Builder SDK?